# Why does my ggplot automatically rearrange my data alphabetically, and is there any way around this?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making a heat map that represents gene expression. The y-axis are the genes being expressed, and on the x-axis are the patients. For some reason ggplot is automatically reordering my y-axis so that the genes are in alphabetical order. My question is: Is there a way for me to leave the genes in the same order as how they were in the data frame?

Here is the original data frame and how I want the y-axis to look like.

```
  GENE ID Patients value
1   DDX27  UBLT001     1
2  YTHDF1  UBLT001     1
3 ARFGAP1  UBLT001     1
4  MAPRE1  UBLT001     1
5    PTK2  UBLT001     1
```

And here is the code for the heatmap:
[image]

```
ggplot(data2, aes(variable, GENE.ID, fill = group)) + 
  geom_tile(color = "white", lwd = .5, linetype = 1) + 
  scale_fill_manual(breaks = levels(data2$group),
                    values = c('#fa6e6e','#f9756d','#f97c6b','#f8836a','#f78a68','#f79167','#f69865','#f69f64','#f5a663','#f4ad61','#f4b560','#f3bc5e','#f2c35d','#f2ca5c','#f1d15a','#f1d859','#f0df57','#efe656','#efed54','#eef453'
))
```

Comment: Hi Evetto, can you use `dput` to give us your actual `data.frame` for `data2`? The example you gave doesn't even have the `group` variable in it, so it can't be "the original data frame." Without that, it's hard to help.

Comment: Try `aes(variable, factor(GENE.ID, unique(GENE.ID)))` to put the y axis in the order it appears in your data frame

Comment: @AllanCameron That seemed to work out! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the order by using the factor levels of the variable you map

```
data2$GENE.ID <- factor(data2$GENE.ID, levels = data2$GENE.ID)

# plot
ggplot(data2, aes(variable, GENE.ID, fill = group)) + 
  geom_tile(color = "white", lwd = .5, linetype = 1) + 
  scale_fill_manual(breaks = levels(data2$group),
                    values = c('#fa6e6e','#f9756d','#f97c6b','#f8836a','#f78a68','#f79167','#f69865','#f69f64','#f5a663','#f4ad61','#f4b560','#f3bc5e','#f2c35d','#f2ca5c','#f1d15a','#f1d859','#f0df57','#efe656','#efed54','#eef453'
))
```